# Replace a DOM element with a different element using CsQuery

Tags: c#, html, dom-manipulation, csquery

A have a HTML document containing a list of links:

```html
  <div class="toc">
     <ul class="content_list">
        <li><a href="...">Chapter 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">Chapter 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">Chapter 3</a></li>
```

Is there a way (using CsQuery) to remove the anchor tags or to replace them with a different element (e.g. a `<span>`) while keeping the text?

The result should be either like this:

```html
  <div class="toc">
     <ul class="content_list">
        <li>Chapter 1</li>
```

or like this:

```html
  <div class="toc">
     <ul class="content_list">
        <li><span>Chapter 1</span></li>
```

Comment: You could probably do it using jquery if that was an option...

Comment: @JoeSager: that's not an option, but if there is a jquery-solution it might also work with CsQuery, since it supports the same DOM-manipulation methods.

Comment: Well, jquery has an html() method, so you can get the html of the li element, remove the anchor tags, and then reset the html to the content of the anchor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var cq = new CsQuery.CQ(@"<div class=""toc""><ul class=""content_list"">
        <li><a href=""..."">Chapter 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=""..."">Chapter 2</a></li>
        <li><a href=""..."">Chapter 3</a></li>
</ul></div>");

cq[".toc > .content_list > li > a"]
    .Select(x => x.Cq())
    .ToList().ForEach(x => x.ReplaceWith(x.Text()));
    //or with a span wrapper
    //.ToList().ForEach(x => x.ReplaceWith(new CsQuery.CQ("<span/>").Text(x.Text())));

cq.Html().Dump();
```

This produce :

```
<ul class="content_list">
    <li>Chapter 1</li>
    <li>Chapter 2</li>
    <li>Chapter 3</li>
</ul>
```